# Adding SignalR to Asp Net Core Project changes all websockets settings?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have an asp net core application which is relying heavily on websockets (both `ClientWebSocket` and the regular `WebSocket` retrieved from the `httpContext`.

I now want to also add the `SignalR` functionality to my app (not to replace the existing ones, as those 2 were coming from external sources). However, I see that the call

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

goes and disables webSocket keep alive functionality. (This is what it calls)

```cs
 // Disable the WebSocket keep alive since SignalR has it's own
    services.Configure<WebSocketOptions>(o => o.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.Zero);
```

I could try using the overload method of `AddSignalR` as follows

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
});
```

but that will change all `WebSocketOptions`, `SignalR` and others alike (defeating the purpose). Is there no way of keeping all my `WebSocketOptions` the default, besides for the `SignalR` one?

Comment: Havent investigated much further as it doesnt seem to disrupt the other sockets. Marking your answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way of keeping all my WebSocketOptions the default,
> besides for the SignalR one?

Actually, based on your scenario and description I would like to mention is that, SignalR has been introduced over WebSockets in order to improve potential drawback found in WebSockets and SignalR has overcome that substantially. Hence, both signalR and WebSockets are not recommended to integrate together.

However, if you still want to persist your existing WebSocket configuration, you should configure WebSockets Middleware and have to inject your custom configuation using [UseWebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-the-middleware). Thus, this way your existing WebSockets settings would prevail. You can configure as following:

```cs
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
};



builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "SignalR hub is running...!");

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** As you can see, websocket's alive interval time has persisted and not changed. Furthermore, I would say, its not recommended which may cause performence issue. On top of this, you can [get more details here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-the-middleware)

Comment: Have to try this. Thanks. You mention that "Hence, both signalR and WebSockets are not recommended to integrate together.". Then what is one meant to do if they have dependencies on other systems which communicate via websockets, (one cannot use SignalR in that case as you dont have control of both sides)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, acutally SingnalR is more verbose than websocket this why its better to use SignalR but if need it then inject your websocket config likewise.

Comment: One cant use signalR if you dont control the client and the server

Comment: Right you are, does the given solution persisting your configuration?

Comment: Havent managed to test yet. I will do

Comment: Sure, test it and let me know if I can assist on anything else further.